# How do I automatically maximize the browser window when a specific url of my site is visited?

Tags: javascript, html

When the browser window is not maximized, the arrangements of the images become scrambled.
How do I automatically maximize the browser whenever my site is visited? How do I restrict viewers from resizing the window?

Comment: You really shouldn't! One of the golden rules of good web development is: **never screw with a visitors window**

Comment: "Bigger then a certain minimum width" and "Maximised" are different things. Most of my computers don't even have the concept of maximised.  Different people run at different resolutions, so while "maximised" might be just fine for you, it might not be wide enough for someone on a narrow display, or it might be stupidly and insanely huge on somebody else's. Leave the window along and create a design that looks good for most people, and is readable for everyone else. People can resize their windows manually if they want to.

Comment: You know, downvoting a question because somebody wants to do something they shouldn't isn't really helpful. The question itself is perfectly clear; a little terse maybe, but there are many worse out there.

Comment: I agree about not downvoting. People who who are looking for a way to do something that is a Bad Idea(tm) should be able to find an answer that guides them to a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

For security and usability reasons, this is utterly impossible.  (or should be)

Give up.

Answer (score 3):

The question should not be about modifying the browser window size (generally frowned upon), but rather about modifying the site layout to work with different window sizes. The window belongs to the user, not you, so you should (in almost all cases), **leave it alone**. Post your layout code and let people take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Be more specific.you want your browser to open using window.open() method or any other ways?
if then,you can pass the screen size as parameter to the window.open() method

for eg:
window.open(URL,widow specification)

in window specification you can set the window size

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Script on programmersheaven.com](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JavaScript-Maximize-Browser-Window-To-Screen).

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2"> 
top.window.moveTo(0,0); 
if (document.all) 
   { top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight); } 
else if 
   (document.layers || document.getElementById) 
   { 
   if 
    (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < 
screen.availWidth)
     { top.window.outerHeight = top.screen.availHeight; 
       top.window.outerWidth = top.screen.availWidth; } 
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: +1 because it's an answer to the question; -1 because it's a terrible idea. +-0 :)

Comment: +1.  Note that this won't work on all browsers.  E.g., see this [chrome discussion](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091).

Answer (score 0):

You should plan to change your disposition and try to get a **fixed** layout for this type of view.

Try to get a pixel-precision layout and don't use only percentage measures.

Messing out with the user's window would only push the user to get off your site asap.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. here's my code. i would want it to have fixed positions such that the contents won't get messed up.

Comment: i only use <center> tags and stuff. :/

Comment: @ian: <center> tags? Oh my, they have been deprecated *looooooong* ago. The <center> cannot hold, the pony the pony.....

Comment: You should probably check out some tutorials like this one http://www.techrepublic.com/article/creating-a-fixed-width-layout-with-css/5314471 and get rid of fixed layouts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maximizing the window you could set a minimum width (or height) for your page. If the user has a smaller window then your width or height set, then he gets scrollbars.

CSS-Properties to use:

min-width
min-height

Example

```
min-width: 500px;
min-height: 300px;
```

More informations here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Comment: Oh no, W3Schools again. Please don't recommend it, it's horrible, full of (security) errors, etc. See http://w3fools.com